# PHP: syntax error, unexpected TC_STRING in /etc/php.ini

Tags: php, syntax, cron

I have a cron job that runs a PHP script and updates and XML file every few minutes.
When the cron job runs the PHP script this error is generated every time.
If I run it in the browser, no errors are generated.

Recently the directory containing the script was copied over to the new site and I had to set some permissions. Apache owns the file and permissions were set to 755.

The line on php.ini that PHP says the syntax error is coming from simply contains:
display_errors = Off           [Security]

Not sure what is going wrong here. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that one line says

```
 display_errors = Off [Security]
```

then there should be a return between `Off` and `[Security]`

Comment: Although it repaired the error and it no longer shows up in the logs, when I have the return after "off" PHP SESSIONs now longer work. Is there anything I can do to appease both?

Comment: Your sessions problem is nothing to do with the issue that you were asking about here